# How to execute a groupby and count fastly on Spark in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I've been trying for a long time to perform a GroupBy and a count() on a Spark DataFrame but and it takes like forever to be processed...

The below line takes about 13 seconds to be processed. From my perspective I think it takes too much time but I don't know how to reduce the processing time.

`matched.limit(100).groupBy('Date','Period').agg(count("*").alias('cnt')).show()`

I'm running on Spark 2.4 with the following config:
Driver: 2 vCPU 8 GB RAM
10 Executors: 2 vCPU 8 GB RAM

Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: @Lamanus I can't tell exactly as I have never ended the process. I tried df.count() but I'm stuck.

Comment: Oh... that's too bad. Is that possible to split the file? How big the file is?

Comment: I have never tried but I know that the number of rows should be somewhere below 70 millions and I think that it shouldn't take so many time to process a count().

Comment: Then the spec is enough. Are you using hadoop? What type of file? Single or multiple?

Comment: I'm running on IBM Watson Studio with a Spark 2.4 environnement. The data comes from multiple .csv files, I read each file and create a Spark DataFrame and  append them all. I've taken Citibike data from 01/2016 to 06/2020 (https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html)

Comment: I have tested for 2 years data from 201601 to 201712 which has `30210312` rows and this is working even in my local pc within a minute. Is your spark cluster working well with other job?

Comment: Yeah everything is working fine. I have filtered the data based on the location and it takes no more than 30 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct way, I think. The spending time will depend on how many rows are there.

```
df.groupBy('Date', 'Period').count().show(10, False)
```